# Failed to load or instantiate TagLibraryValidator

Tags: java, maven, jsp, tomcat, jstl

I am trying to deploy a war file on Tomcat and every time I try to run it, I get an error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.createValidator(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:348)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:195)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:431)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:489)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1445)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:144)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:244)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:105)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:206)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:385)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:362)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:346)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:603)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:399)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

I can see it the JSTL library missing, but I do have it added into my pom file. My dependencies are:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jdom/jdom -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.19.v20190610</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.19.v20190610</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-util -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.19.v20190610</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.servicemix/servicemix -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.servicemix</groupId>
        <artifactId>servicemix</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

I have looked at some other threads on stack overflow and replicate the answers but they just didn't help. Am I missing some extra dependencies? From the error does seem like so. But cant say. I am using Servlet 4.0 and Tomcat 9.0.22.

Comment: From a little googling I found that the class `JstlCoreTLV` is from Apache Standard Taglib, do I have to delete the jstl I havenow and add this:
`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>taglibs-standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if its correct or not, but I was able to get it to work by copying the jstl.jar into the Tomcat/lib folder, and removing the dependency from the pom file.